# How to use the mpatches.Patch in matplotlib to add custom labels to a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, legend

I am trying to manually add `legends` but they are not showing. I would like to use the `matplotlib pathes` instead of `seaborn` hue so that I can control my `colours` and handle the duplicate products.

```
Dec = df.event_ID.value_counts().nlargest(10).keys().tolist()

text = [Typ[i] for i in Dec]
```

when we print text output

```
print(text)

['JK)',
 'CDE',
 'GAMED',
 'JK',
 'DTA',
 'AU365',
 'BCD',
 'BCD',
 'ADD',
 'ADD']
```

Here are the colours and my approach

```
color=["peru", "crimson", "magenta", "dimgrey", "forestgreen", "orange", 
       "dodgerblue", "aliceblue", "gold", "firebrick"]
df.groupby("event_ID")["Typ"].size().nlargest(10).plot(kind="bar", color=color)
plt.legend(color, text)
```

But I cant see the text in the plot

Answer (score 1):

You may want to:

```
df1=df.groupby("event_ID")["Typ"].size().nlargest(10)
plt.bar(df1.index,df1,  color=color,label=text) 
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
```

This will have your legend at the upper right corner but you are of course free to change it. You can read the documentation [plt legend](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) for more detailed usage. 
Also notice that

`df.groupby('keywords')['number'].size().plot(kind='bar',color=color,label=text)`

does not work, because, `label` only takes a string, but not a list.